# Configuring Google Domain to point to Azure website

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I have an site hosted on Azure that I am trying to point a domain from Google Domains to.

My current configuration is as follows:

```
Name       Type    Data 
 @         A       XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 
 www       CNAME   history-podcasts.azurewebsites.net
 awverify  CNAME   awverify.history-podcasts.com
```

I am following the instructions from here: [Configuring a custom domain name for an Azure Website.](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/)

When I go to the Azure portal to Manage Domain and attempt to enter the url in DOMAIN NAMES, I get the following message:

> A CNAME record pointing from history-podcasts.com to history-podcasts.azurewebsites.net was not found. Alternative record awverify.history-podcasts.com to awverify.history-podcasts.azurewebsites.net was not found either

When I go to the URL for the domain, I get the following message:

> The website you have attempted to reach is not available in this Microsoft Azure Web Sites region. This could be due to one of several reasons:
>
> 1. The web site owner has registered a custom domain to point to the Microsoft Azure Web Site, but has not yet configured Azure to recognize it. Click here to read more.
>
> When a site owner wants to use a custom domain with a Microsoft Azure Web Sites website, Azure needs to be configured to recognize the custom domain name, so that it can route the request to the appropriate server in the region. After registering the domain with a domain provider and configuring a DNS CNAME record to point to the site's Azurewebsites.net address (for example, contoso.azurewebsites.net), the website owner also needs to go to the Azure Portal and configure the site for the new domain. Click here to learn more about configuring the custom domains for a web site.

This is the same configuration settings I am currently using for several domains through Namecheap with Azure hosting and they work as intended.

Comment: Have you created the "awverify" entry on DNS?  http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/#awverify

Comment: Yes I have, to no effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT:**

To summarize, here are the steps you need to take:

**1) Create CNAME record redirecting user from your domain to Azure specified domain using tools provided by your DNS hosting service**

This step will ensure that when going to `www.history-podcasts.com` user will transparently be taken to `history-podcasts.azurewebsites.net`

```
Type: CNAME
Name: www
Value: history-podcasts.azurewebsites.net
```

**IMPORTANT:** Please note that it takes time for DNS servers to update their records therefore you should wait around 30 minutes before continuing.

**2) Redirect your naked domain to subdomain using DNS hosting service tools**

This step will ensure that when going to `history-podcasts.com` user will be redirected to `www.history-podcasts.com`

For Google Domains you can follow this guide [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2518373?hl=en).

**3) Add your domain to Azure Website**

This step will assure Azure that you own the domain and you want your site to be reachable using specified domain name.

- Login into https://manage.windowsazure.com/
- Navigate `Websites -> [Your Website] -> Configure`
- Scroll down to `Domain names`
- Click `Manage Domains` (note that custom domains can only be used when in the Shared, Basic, or Standard modes)
- Add your domain `www.history-podcasts.com`

At this  point you should be able to reach your web site using both `history-podcasts.com` and `www.history-podcasts.com` domain names.

If your website requires HTTPS, you will have to take extra steps:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/

Comment: This part of of the steps that I have done which I outlined above.

Comment: In response to you edit, these are my current settings. This is identical to how I have my Namecheap domains pointing to Azure sites configured, but for some reason it is not working with Google Domains. Thanks for looking into this further.

Comment: Please note "awverify" prefix for CNAME. In your original post you don't have it!

Comment: Yes, sorry, I thought I added that as well.

Comment: Could it be that you have to register www.history-podcasts.com in Azure Custom domains as CNAME can map only subdomains?

Comment: That did work. I swear I tried that at one point but Azure rejected the "www." part. However, the site is in https so now I am getting the "This Connection is Untrusted" message when going to the site.

Comment: DNS record changes take time to propagate to all DNS servers. That could be reason it didn't work when you tried it. To solve certificate error, please follow this guide: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/

Comment: I updated my answer to summarize all the steps needed. Please review and mark as answer if it helped! :)

Comment: Is it possible to setup HSTS with this?  i.e. as the redirect from the domain to the subdomain occurs before the `Strict-Transport-Security` header can be sent.